# Inline View Qustion

Tags: oracle, inline-view

Perhaps someone can assist with designing a query to meet these requirements.  I'm going to need this to be part of an inline view which will be joined to a larger query.

I have the basic table of email addresses:

```
EMAIL
jon@a.com
art@b.com
```

Then I have a table, called UPLOAD_HISTORY.  Sample data:

```
EMAIL        FILETYPE   FILENAME
jon@a.com    1          file1.txt 
jon@a.com    2          filex.txt 
jon@a.com    4          fileb.txt
```

Then there is the table of file types:

```
FILE ID     FILE TYPE
   1         TYPE A
   2         TYPE B
   3         TYPE C
   4         TYPE D
```

If I perform a query, and outer join the UPLOAD_HISTORY and FILE_TYPES, I would get something like this:

```
EMAIL     FILETYPE     FILENAME
jon@a.com    1          file1.txt
jon@a.com    2          filex.txt
             3
jon@a.com    4          fileb.txt
```

What I need for the missing record, is to fill in the missing values from the UPLOAD_HISTORY table.   My ideal result set would look like this:

```
EMAIL        FILETYPE   FILENAME      STATUS
jon@a.com    1          file1.txt     1
jon@a.com    2          filex.txt     1
jon@a.com    3                        0
jon@a.com    4          fileb.txt     1
```

I am looking to get all file types, an email for every line, and a status of 1 if there is a record for that file type, or 0 if there is not........

Sometimes there may be criteria passed.  I may ask for a specific file type, or not.

If a particular email does not have any entries in the UPLOAD_HISTORY table, is it possible to get empty records?

```
EMAIL        FILETYPE   FILENAME     STATUS
jon@a.com    1          file1.txt     1
jon@a.com    2          filex.txt     1
jon@a.com    3                        0
jon@a.com    4          fileb.txt     1
art@b.com    1                        0
art@b.com    2                        0
art@b.com    3                        0
art@b.com    4                        0
```

However, I could ask for just File Type 1:

```
EMAIL     FILETYPE     FILENAME    STATUS
jon@a.com    1          file1.txt     1
art@b.com    1                        0
```

Thanks

Comment: Ask one question a time. Please confirm which output do you actually want to see and restrict this question to that one only.

Comment: Please don't use HTML tags when posting code. The markdown for code is much simpler, works nicely with the StackOverflow renderer and is easier to fix. To format a code block use the `{}` button on the editor menu or simply indent each line by four spaces. For inline use backticks `\``

Answer (score 0):

Left join from file types to history:

```
select EMAIL, FILETYPE, FILENAME, nvl(STATUS, 0) as STATUS
from file_type
left join upload_history on FILETYPE = FILE_ID
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query is still omitting the missing file types.

Comment: @LandonStatis impossible. This query is guaranteed to return all file types.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CROSS JOIN on `email` and `file_type` to get all the combinations, then LEFT OUTER JOIN on `upload_history` to get the results you want.

Assuming there is at most one record in `upload_history` for each combination this should work nicely:

```
select eft.email
       , eft.filetype
       , uh.filename
       , nvl2(uh.filename, 1, 0) as status
from   ( select email, file_id, filetype
         from email 
         cross join file_type ) eft
left outer join upload_history uh
    on uh.email = eft.email
    and uh.filetype = eft.filetype
order by eft.email
       , eft.filetype
```

You haven't specified what you want to happen if there are multiple records in `upload_history` for each combination. Maybe one row per `filename` is correct. But the purpose of the `status` column seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple record in UPLOAD_HISTORY.   But the reason for status is:  if the particular email has no records in UPLOAD_HISTORY, we will want it returned, just with the email value and status, which the application will use.   1 = data, 0 = no data.     But, I'll check out this query you provided.